# GUI with tkinter, 2 buttons touched together

Tags: python-3, raspberry-pi-desktop, tkinter

Have written a GUI (touchscreen) for my Pi in Python 3 with tkinter. It works in fullscreen. I do not want to have an extra button for shutting down the Pi but when I push 2 buttons together. How can I manage this?

postet this question to 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/61162648/11119062

Comment: This is a general programming question and does not belong to Raspberry Pi. I think you will get faster better answers at https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: thanx. thougt Pi-users have more experience with touchscreens...

Comment: You are talking about a GUI (raspberry-pi-desktop). There is nothing said about a touchscreen. So what do you mean? Two buttons on a touchcreen, or in a GUI?

Comment: Sorry, I meant a touchscreen. It's not easy to hold 2 buttons with one mouse.

Comment: Thought I had was to create a global variable with the initial value of 0.  Then in each buttons pressed callback action add one to the value and if the value equals 2 do your shutdown.  In each buttons release action subtract 1 from the value.  Sounds odd but I think that should work.  No way to test as I needed a new disk rather than the screen this month :-(. If you get stuck with the code I’ll see if I can knock something up for you to test.

Comment: Thx, I try this later.

Comment: Sorry for late feedback. But I managed it holding 1 Button for 5 seconds. I done this in a class.